# print matrix from file

Tags: c

I use this code for loading matrix:

```
 FILE *inputMatrix=fopen("file","r");
 fscanf(inputMatrix,"%d",&num);
 for(i=0;i<num;++i){
    for(j=0;j<num+1;++j){
        fscanf(inputMatrix,"%f",&A[i][j]);
    }
 }
 fclose(inputMatrix);
 int numRow=num;
 int numColumn=num+1;
```

and then I want to print it in main by method printMatrix:

```
void printMatrix(int numColumn, int numRow ,int matrix[numRow][numColumn]){
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   printf("nc: %i, nr: %i\n",numColumn,numRow);
    for(i = 0 ; i < numRow ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < numColumn ; j++)
        {
            printf("%.2f  ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Here is the question. When I use in main: `printf("matrix[1][1] is %f",matrix[1][1])` => it is loaded successfully from file, but when I try to print it by my method, which prints as well, I get 0.00 for every piece in matrix. Why so? Am I missing some referrence?

Comment: Hello, is it possible to have a functional peace of code ?

Comment: Show us the main and the signature of the function for loading the matrix from the file. And why the second `for` is `for(j=0;j<num+1;++j)`? The matrix is Nx(N+1) ?

Comment: Post your `main()` code, especially where file is loaded and `printMatrix()` is called.

Comment: It seems like your matrix variable not initialized, so check it. If possible put your full source code.

Comment: I have added my code, yes matrix is Nx(N+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float A[10][11];
```

but...

```
void printMatrix(int numColumn, int numRow ,int matrix[numRow][numColumn]){
```

A `float` definition, but the method is expecting an `int` array. I'm stunned this compiled, but `gcc` threw off enough warnings that should give one pause:

```
$ gcc -o 5448492 5448492.c 
5448492.c:30: warning: conflicting types for ‘printMatrix’
5448492.c:24: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘printMatrix’ was here
5448492.c: In function ‘printMatrix’:
5448492.c:37: warning: format ‘%.2f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

Because C requires **all but the first array index** to be known at compile time, you can make the program function by declaring a prototype for `printMatrix()` that includes the *last* array index size. (I got it wrong in my comment. Sorry.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printMatrix(int numColumn, int numRow ,float matrix[][11]);

int main (int argc,char *argv[]) {

  int num;
  int i,j;
  float A[10][11];

  FILE *inputMatrix=fopen("yourfile.in","r");
  fscanf(inputMatrix,"%d",&num);
  int numRow=num;
  int numColumn=num+1;

  for(i=0;i<numRow;++i){
     for(j=0;j<numColumn;++j){
         fscanf(inputMatrix,"%f",&A[i][j]);
     }
  }
  fclose(inputMatrix);

  printMatrix(numColumn,numRow,A);

  return 0;
}


void printMatrix(int numColumn, int numRow ,float matrix[][11]){
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   printf("nc: %i, nr: %i\n",numColumn,numRow);
     for(i = 0 ; i < numRow ; i++)
     {
       for(j = 0 ; j < numColumn ; j++)
       {
         printf("%f  ", matrix[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
     }
     printf("\n");
}
```

And the output:

```
$ ./5448492 
nc: 3, nr: 2
1.000000  1.000000  3.000000  
2.000000  2.000000  5.000000
```

I fiddled with other stuff while tracking this one down (and standardized the indents at two spaces; it's awfully small, but consistency on non-favorite beats inconsistency every time), but I'm pretty sure the only thing I changed of substance was the prototype of the function to include the *last* array dimension.

Comment: But fixing that alone doesn't seem to fix the whole program. I'm leery of passing multi-dimensional arrays to a function in C; I thought all-but-the-last index had to be known _at compile time_, but even fixing that gives results I can't explain.

Comment: yea, you are right... it gives me only first line of numbers correctly and then some very long error numbers...

Comment: See my answer. Since you have a fixed array of 11 columns: `A[10][11]`, you'll have to hard code the `11` in other places as well.

Comment: @Hmyzak, I was wrong in my earlier comment; **all but the first index** have to be known at compile time. See working code in answer. :)

Comment: @sarnold: Exactly and the *first index* **must be passed** as a parameter.

Comment: In the function's declaration and definition: the `numRow` in `[numRow][numColumn]` and `numColumn` in `[numColumn][11]` are really ignored by the compiler. It's better to have `float matrix[][11]` to show that any matrix with 11 columns and any number of rows can be used.

Comment: @ypercube, I waffled about leaving them in or not; on the one hand, they are documentation about how the function is _supposed_ to be used. On the other hand, they _mean_ nothing to the compiler, and that could cause confusion down the road. I think you're right though, I'll remove them.

Comment: What do we do if we want the matrix A to be a double variable?

Comment: @dblazevski, you would need to modify the declarator for `A` to store `double` instead of `float`, you would need to modify the `printMatrix()` prototype and definition to accept a `double` array, and all the `scanf()` and `printf()` statements would need to be modified to expect `double` arguments rather than `float`. C's lack of generic typing can be painful sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

May be you should use `double` or `float` type for matrix array.

Comment: I am using float for the matrix array

Comment: `void printMatrix(int numColumn, int numRow ,` **float** `matrix[numRow][numColumn])`

Answer (score 2):

You have an integer matrix, therefore you should use %d instead of %f / %.2f for scanning/printing

Comment: I have to use %f because of print of matrix, which can have float numbers after some computing

Comment: In that case you have to change the parameter type of matrix to float also!

Answer (score 1):

SInce you use an array 10x11, `11` should be hard coded in other places as well. When passing a multidimensional array like this, all dimensions except the highest must be hard coded. Otherwise, you will get erroneous results.

The reason is that your functions think that the array has `numColumn` columns but the array in memory has actually 11 columns.

I would make these changes:

```
include ...
...

-- note the *float** and the **[11]**
void printMatrix(int numColumn, int numRow ,float matrix[][11]);

int main (int argc,char *argv[]) {

  int num;
  int i,j;
  float A[10][11];  
...
}

-- note the *float** and the **[11]**
void printMatrix(int numColumn, int numRow ,float matrix[][11]){
...
}
```